# Pandas Dataframe slice fillna value not being assigned (not working)

Tags: python, pandas, fillna, pandas-loc

I tried this

```
values = {'BsmtQual':'None','BsmtCond':'None', 'BsmtExposure':'None', 'BsmtFinType1':'None', 'BsmtFinType2':'None'}
df_test.loc[:, ('BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2')].fillna(value=values, inplace=True)
```

and this

```
values = {'BsmtQual':'None','BsmtCond':'None', 'BsmtExposure':'None', 'BsmtFinType1':'None', 'BsmtFinType2':'None'}
df_test.loc[:, ['BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2']].fillna(value=values, inplace=True)
```

and this

```
values = {'BsmtQual':'None','BsmtCond':'None', 'BsmtExposure':'None', 'BsmtFinType1':'None', 'BsmtFinType2':'None'}
df_test[['BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2']].fillna(value=values, inplace=True)
```

just this

```
df_test[['BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2']].fillna('None', inplace=True)
```

one line with .loc

```
df_test.loc[:, ['BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2']].fillna('None', inplace=True)
```

and nothing worked! Please help me out

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign it. For example:

```
df_test.loc[:, ('BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2')] = df_test.loc[:, ('BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2')].fillna(value=values)
```

Comment: but I used inplace=True

Comment: it worked though.. but why didn't 'inplace=True' didn't work :/

Comment: When you are using `.loc`, you are generating a new object, which is a slice of the original dataframe. `inplace=True` is applied to this new object, not the original dataframe, hence you see no changes in the original dataframe.